# How to setup a router as a sub local network

Tags: networking

The question is not phrased very well but bear with me here, I have zero experience in network talk.

At home we have a D-link modem/router but my brother decided it would a good idea to turn on AP isolation meaning devices can’t talk to each other, which is not very good for me because I have a linux machine with all my media and bulk storage that I want offload storage and downloading things to so I dug up an old Huawei router that I want setup in the following way:

It (the Huawei box) connects to the main box (D-link) to get internet access and then my linux box and any other devices I might have connect to the Huawei box in a way that they would be able to talk to each other in a sort off subnet thing without ever talking to the D-link router meaning it would be inaccessible from my devices.

The D-link router is a DSL-2750U and it has 4 ports marked LAN and 1 marked WAN, the Huawei is an HG532s and has 4 marked LAN. I have zero control over the D-link router and full control on everything else.

It would much help if someone could guide me through setting this thing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/setup-a-second-wireless-router-on-your-home-network/) tutorial should help you do what you want. A quote from the article:

> In this post, I am going to show you how you can add a second wireless router to the network that will be on a different subnet then the first router, but will still connect to the Internet using the main router as a gateway.

I believe that is what you want to do based on your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a TP-link repeater so I put that in the closet with the linux box, connected ethernet between them and setup the repeater with an ssid different from the main router. Now I can go back to doing nothing but watching pokemon :)